# scripts and stylesheets not loading while reload in angularjs SPA

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

**Index Page :**

```
  <ng-view></ng-view>
```

**Angular Controller :**

```
    when('/', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'site/home',
        controller: 'indexController'
    }).

    when('/site/help', {
        templateUrl: 'site/help',
        controller: 'indexController'
    }).
```

**Help Page Content :**

Some help Content

The Problem is when I navigate from Index page by using /site/help link it shows me help page content with menu of index page.

But when I reload the page it only shows help page content without any styles or javascripts loaded.

Comment: Home page like this :

   <base href="/">

<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
      <ng-view></ng-view>

Comment: You have to redirect all subpages to index.html.

Comment: Looks like you are using HTML5Mode. Please refer this URL. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Either turn of html5mode or add an internal redirect to home page if the page is not retrieved via xhr (Look for headers)

Comment: It is working but how can I achieve the same with html5 mode as true?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should put `ng-view` tag in index.html, because this page is the main page and the other pages are part of that:

```
<body> 
    //some content
    <ng-view></ng-view> 
</body>
```

Comment: <html>
<head >

    <title></title>

    <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
//Navigation menu with anchor tags
<ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
</html>
Already I have used this structure.But still when partial view gets refreshed it only shows partial view content without any style, scripts loaded and no menu of index.html page

Comment: I'm developing the application in Angularjs with ASP MVC as back end. Do I need to modify RoutesConfig or something else?

Comment: $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!'); used in angular route config also